# Wix Bootstrapper bundle how to specify NOT condition for bal:Condition

Tags: wix, bootstrapper

What I want to do is:

```
<bal:Condition Message="Microsoft .NET v4.5.2 is required.">Not (WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_452_OR_LATER_INSTALLED)</bal:Condition>
```

But it doesn't seem to recognize this syntax.  How do I specify NOT in a bal:Condition (and where the heck would this ever be documented?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So I couldn't figure out how to get that syntax right, nor could I find any decent documentation, anywhere, on this stuff, so I resorted to a registry search:

```
    <util:RegistrySearch
    Id="Is452There"
    Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full"
    Value="Release" Variable="Is452There" Win64="no" />
```

and then:

```
    <bal:Condition Message="Microsoft .NET v4.5.2 is required.">Is452There>="379893"</bal:Condition>
```

This seemed to do the trick.